# Run karma as a service

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have installed karma for testing my AngularJS application on a virtual machine. I use the debug interface for that by browsing to the default location, `http://localhost:9876/`. This all works fine. What I want to do is expose this application to an external url, http://domain.com:9876.

This also works, the problem that I have is that I need to manually start karma and stay logged in the virtual machine. Is there a way to run karma as a service, in order to avoid needing to have a user logged in the virtual machine? I tried using forever, https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever but it seems that this needs a *.js file to start, and not a different application, like karma.

Anyone have any idea on how this could be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, you can run karma with grunt ([karma-grunt-plugin](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma)). And depending on your VM OS you register grunt as a service :

- Windows : sc.exe command
- Linux : customize your /etc/init.d/skeleton file and then call "service [name] start" (for more information google "run a program as a service linux"). Check that your "grunt" command can be executed from everywhere. If not, then complete your $Path variable and/or ln -s grunt on /usr/bin...

Maybe it is possible to do it with karma directly but I've never tried.

Comment: I will try this in the following days and come back with a response. Thanks for taking the time to answer.